# how to sum multiple lists of array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sum

this is the full script, and the last ljp(r)'s output is multiple floats, and I wish to get a sum of all that floats.
I ve tried casting into a list, or sum(), but none worked, those all gave me the exact same output as what I have right now.
please give me help:(

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'lj-0200.xyz'
xyz_file = np.genfromtxt(fname=filename,skip_header=2,dtype='unicode')
xyz = open(filename)

atom_quantity = int(xyz.readline())
atom_coordinates = (xyz_file[:,1:])
atom_coordinates = atom_coordinates.astype(float)

import itertools as it
import math 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# the Total number of the iteration = 2 pair combination
# change coordinate data into array 
array = np.array(atom_coordinates)

# apply combination for all atoms on data
# all duplicate-pair are deleted 
combinations = it.combinations(array,2)

for combination in combinations:
    
    array_comb = np.array(combination)

    # Show the coordinates of first element and second element of each pair resulted from combination
    #print("First element in the pair is", array_comb[:1], "and second is", array_comb[1:2])
    
    # Distance 'r' between the pair : 
    
    # Compute left side 
    # r^2 = ((x_1)^2 - (x_2)^2)+((y_1)^2 - (y_2)^2)+((z_1)^2 - (z_2)^2)
    array_xyz_sq = abs((array_comb[:1])**2 - (array_comb[1:2])**2)
    #print("The value of left side equation is",array_xyz_sq)
    
    # r^2 = ((x_1)^2 - (x_2)^2)+((y_1)^2 - (y_2)^2)+((z_1)^2 - (z_2)^2)
    array_xyz_sum =  np.sum(array_xyz_sq, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
    #print("Sum of Left side of the equation",array_xyz_sum)
    
    # Compute r, the distance 
    r = math.sqrt(array_xyz_sum)
    #print("R value for each pair is", r)
    
    # LJpotential 
    
    def ljp(n):
        # There are r=0 data, which will cause 1/0 error, so skip LJP calcualtion when r=0
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            # Formula from #1 assignment 
            return 4*1*((1/n)**12 - (1/n)**6)
 
    print(ljp(r))
    # SUM of all the values of list_ljp output is Desried 

# This function was one of the attempts.. 
    def castToList(x): #casts x to a list
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return x
        elif isinstance(x, str):
            return [x]
        try:
            return list(x)
        except TypeError:
            return [x]

    list_ljp = castToList(ljp(r))
    
    list_ljp = castToList(ljp(r))
    sum_ = np.array(list_ljp).sum()
    print(sum_)
```

output :

```
-0.004894362613156397
-0.005284630990696516
-0.39715504708587857
-0.23893503091440427
-0.0021751402527176167
-0.02151541521026157
-0.028713108430138003
-0.0037546817391838857
 ......
```

desired : the sum of all the floats..

Comment: Your script isn't complete.  Is there some sort of repeat or iteration on `r`.  The first block just looks like repeated `print(lisp_ljp)`, not a list or array.

Comment: I don't see you creating `list_ljp`

Comment: I deleted all the list_ljp part because even without doing so, just ljp(r) shows me all the float. do you think I should keep the list_ljp (casting ljp(r) into list)) ?

Comment: sum needs a list or array of numbers.  It can't use a screen full of printed strings.

Comment: question edited.. still getting the same result, even after changing it into a list. I am guessing my method of turning ljp(r) into a list is wrong? could you suggest a correct way to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  You are making each `combination` into a list, or array, and applying `sum`, but you aren't collecting results (at any level) for all combinations.  Doing a `print` inside a loop can be useful for debugging purposes, but it doesn't nothing to collect results for the whole loop.  `r` produced by `math.sqrt` is just one number.  Making a list `[r]` does nothing significant.  Maybe you need to experiment with a much simpler `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either accumulate the sum in a variable initialized outside the loop or fill a *list*, and compute the sum at the end.

```
acc = []
for combination in combinations:
    # ...
    acc += ljp(r)
    
list_ljp_sum = math.sum(acc)
```

Comment: when I do that, I get the result of multiple floats.. like : -0.004894362613156397
-0.005284630990696516
-0.39715504708587857
-0.23893503091440427
-0.0021751402527176167
-0.02151541521026157
-0.028713108430138003
-0.0037546817391838857
-0.010478577414797552
-0.0023003459413167464
-0.0014292827917506317
-0.09388883810402544
-0.009535847880922233.   .

Comment: and I need to that the sum of all those floats..

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: "Error : 'float' object is not iterable" when I execute that suggestion

Comment: I  tried making it into a list and summing - edited the question still end up with the same result. I am guessing my way to turning ljp(r) into a list is wrong. could you suggest a way to do that correctly?

Comment: What type is `ljp(r)`?